# Firefox print adds page break and cuts off content

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

I have a layout with several divs in divs like in this image [Page in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03rdx.png). Now i want make this page printable, for Chrome and Safari it works, but Firefox shows the yellow `div` on a new page, instead of printing it directly after the green `div`. Also if there is content in the red or grey `div` which is higher than the page (it is much text also wrapped in divs) Firefox cuts of the the text at the end of the page. [Print preview in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC0XL.png)

I tried `page-break-before`, `page-break-after` and `page-break-inside` but it did't work.

The HTML looks like this:

```html
<div style="border: 5px solid hotpink">
    <header style="border: 5px solid blue"></header>
    <div style="border: 5px solid green">
        <div style="border: 5px solid purple"></div>
        <div style="border: 5px solid pink"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 5px solid yellow">
        <div style="border: 5px solid red"></div>
        <div style="border: 5px solid grey"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS properties for these divs, i added the width and heigth properties only to show the results in the images.

hotpink:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 24px;
outline-color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
```

blue:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
display: block;
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 156px;
line-height: 24px;
max-width: 100%;
page-break-after: auto;
text-align: center;
```

green:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 364px;
justify-content: center;
line-height: 24px;
outline-color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
```

purple:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 364px;
justify-content: center;
line-height: 24px;
margin-right: 30px;
outline-color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
width: 385px;
```

pink:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 300px;
line-height: 24px;
outline-color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
width: 400px;
```

yellow:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
display: flex;
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
justify-content: center;
line-height: 24px;
outline-color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
page-break-before: auto;
```

red:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 800px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-top: 20px;
outline-color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 5px;
width: 440px;
```

grey:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 800px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-top: 20px;
outline-color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-top: 5px;
width: 445px;
```

And a div inside the grey div containg text:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
display: none;
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 24px;
outline-color: rgb(41, 43, 44);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
```

Any idea, why

1. Firefox renders the yellow `div` on a new page?
2. the text in the grey `div` gets cut off, if it does not fit in one page?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question is a bit long and unwieldy. You may want to consider shortening it and using a [**stack snippet**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @matthias did you find the solution to this issue? Could you share it with us? Thanks